# Why don't we need storage permission to download a file through DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-download-manager

I'm downloading a file through android DownloadManager with de function below.

```
 private fun downloadFile() {
        val downloadManager: DownloadManager =
            getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

        val request =
            DownloadManager.Request(Uri.
            parse("https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"))

        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }
}
```

The download occurs normally without any storage permissions.

Does the download manager work without storage permissions?
I can't find the answer in the official documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DownloadManager` delegates the downloading work to a separate system-supplied app. That app has rights to write to a few locations, even if your app does not.

Comment: It makes sense to me!
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 3):

If u use [setDestinationInExternalPublicDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

For applications **targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above**, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not needed and the dirType must be one of the known public directories like
Environment#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, Environment#DIRECTORY_PICTURES, Environment#DIRECTORY_MOVIES, etc.

And for [setDestinationUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri))

For applications **targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above**, WRITE EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is not needed and the uri must refer to a path within the directories owned by the application (e.g. Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)) or a path within the top-level Downloads directory (as returned by Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String) with Environment#DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).

Comment: Seems like this is not true for pre Q devices. For an application with both complie and target SDK 33 the DownloadManager crashes with SecurityException android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE while running on pre 10 android phones (Checked 8 and 9).